# Unix timestamp format conversion

Tags: go

A unix_timestamp of `1405936049` corresponds to: `2014-07-21 09:47:29`.  My goal is to derive the latter form from the timestamp.

After reading the format documentation, I came up with the following:

```
fmt.Println(time.Unix(1405936049, 0).Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
```

which yields: `2014-07-21 02:47:29`, which makes sense, since `time.Unix(1405936049, 0)` gives: `2014-07-21 02:47:29 -0700 PDT` (to be clear, I want: 2014-07-21 09:47:29, the hour is incorrect).

I'm sure if I knew the correct terminology, I'd be able to find a solution in the documentation, but at this point, I'm uncertain how to tell the parser to account for `-0700` or perhaps an alternative solution would be to use something besides `time.Unix()`, so that the resulting time would have already accounted for the hour difference?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But http://play.golang.org/p/cyeh8MQYUy already give you `09:47:29`, not `02:47:29`

Comment: @VonC: "In the playground the time begins at 2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC." [Go Playgroud: About](http://play.golang.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the UTC time, not your local PDT time. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Unix(1405936049, 0).UTC().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
}
```

Output:

```
2014-07-21 09:47:29
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`Location`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Location) for this:

```
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Paris")
fmt.Println(time.Unix(1405936049, 0).In(loc).Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
```

I think the location you want is "UTC", but I let you check (otherwise, here is [a list of all available locations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)). The reason why in playground the format is already `09:47:29` is that [playground does not include locations](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4755) and uses UTC by default.